# PHP Array in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using one database in mysql in which it is having a record of sources:

```
IP (sip)
Destination IP (dip) 
Source Port (sport) 
Destination Port (dport)
```

When doing select query

```
select count(sport) as port, sport from IPtable limit 20);
```

the result is as follows:

```
port sport
3    80
5    8080
15   21
3    20
25   443
16   1234
49   2352
15   2353
```

I want to group these ports like

```
web (80, 8080, 443)
ftp (20, 21)
chat (2352, 2353)
others("rest other ports")
```

and want output result as

```
count   port
=============
33      web
18      ftp
16      application
64      others
```

Please help because I want to create pi chart from this output.

Comment: create a temp table port | portKind join with it and group by portKind?

Comment: first you'd have to build up a list of what each port represents. mysql won't know that 80 == web. Once you've got that table with port-to-service mappings, then your query becomes a simple `join` with `group_concat()`.